# Passing a vector of specific size to a function

Tags: c++

```cpp
/* Class Hand represents a hand in Hold'em poker.
Namely the best 5 cards formed from 7 cards: 2 player's pocket cards
and 5 cards from the board.*/
class Hand {
public:
  Hand(const std::vector<CardPtr>& cardseq);
  /*...*/
};
```

Constructor expects a vector of Cards. The internal logic of the class is based on the assumption that given vector consists of 7 cards. But I'm not controlling it. I can throw an exception when `cardseq.size() != 7` in constructor. But is there any other way of keeping the behaviour of instance of class meaningful by controlling the size of initializing vector?

Comment: Do you have to use a vector?

Comment: You would probably be better off using 7 input parameters or passing in an array.

Comment: 'Throwing in the constructor' gives me a chill...

Comment: @MichaelDorgan Why? Maybe it's not the best solution here, but it's usually the only way to indicate failure within a constructor. Better than ending up with an invalid object but no indication that this has happened.

Comment: I guess I've read too many horror stories about dynamic memory allocation/rule of 3 stuff done wrong is all.  Don't mind me :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If your data structure is always an array of 7 cards, then why not use `std::array<CardPtr, 7>`?

Comment: Yes. Thank you. That's what I was looking for. With fixed size container the compiler will control it, no failures during runtime.